# free char pointer inside a function

Tags: c, function-pointers

Main:

```
char *tmpip;
tmpip = get_public_ip();
```

function get_public_ip:

```
char * get_public_ip(void){
    char *ipresult;

    if(((ipresult = malloc(17))) == NULL){
        perror("malloc on pub ip");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(fgets(ipresult, 16, tmpfp) == NULL){
        perror("fgets error pubip");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(tmpfp);
    return ipresult;
}
```

My question is:
it is good to do inside the main `free(tmpip)` or it is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good way of coding: you `malloc()` some memory in a function and `free()` it when not needed anymore. Be sure to comment your function or prototype that it will `malloc()` the memory needed, so you know that you have to `free()` it.

Comment: basically you need to `free` everything on the same level as you `malloc`ed them, counting a creation function (such as yours, which malloc and return) on the level it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it be wrong? You don't really have any other option to free the allocated buffer somewhere else... It's idiomatic in C to call a function that allocates memory, then make the caller (outer) function resposible for freeing that memory.

Comment: @polslinux `free(tmpip)`, the other option doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

If dynamic allocation is used, then freeing the pointer with `free(tmpip)` is definitely good! The function `get_public_ip` just needs to document that to release resources the caller must ensure `free` is called on the return value.

An alternative would be to provide a function `void free_public_ip(char*buf) {free(buf);}`, and document that to release resources the caller must use that. This gives you some flexibility in future to change how the memory is allocated, without calling code changing. It's certainly not necessary.

In my opinion it doesn't really make sense to `malloc` a small fixed-size buffer like that. The header file for `get_public_ip` could `#define PUBLIC_IP_SIZE (17)` and take a `char*` parameter, then the caller could do:

```
char tmpip[PUBLIC_IP_SIZE];
get_public_ip(tmpip);
// no more thinking required
```

Instead of:

```
char *tmpip = get_public_ip();
// code here, perhaps does more things that could fail, 
// maybe some thinking required to ensure every code path passes through:
free(tmpip);
```

If that number `17` can change in future without the opportunity to re-compile the calling code (for instance if this is a library and you require binary compatibility), then dynamic allocation would be justified.